# Удалить определенное количество элементов из массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6 ...];
```

Пытаюсь удалить из него 2 пятерки. Т.е. что бы получилось так `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 ...]`

Предполагаю, что это можно сделать счетчиком. т.е. цикл проходится по массиву, находит `5`, удаляет ее, добавляет в переменную `+ 1` и так до тех пор пока переменная не будет `= 2`. Возможно кто то знает более удачное решение?

Comment: Да вполне себе решение..... можно конечно два раза написать `arr.splice(arr.findIndex(el => el === 5), 1);` но это более замороченно, т.к. включается цикл аж два раза. Хотя визуально выглядит проще

Comment: Если пятёрки будут всегда подряд идти, ровно так, как в примере, тогда вообще достаточно дойти до первой и потом отрезать 2 элемента начиная с позиции первой пятёрки

Answer (score 0):

Набросал вам тут какую-то более-менее простую для восприятия функцию в полудреме, которой скармливаете массив, элемент который оттуда нужно удалить и в каком количестве.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6];

function deleteElArr(arr, delElement, amount) {
  if (!arr.includes(delElement)) {
    return 'В массиве нет такого элемента';
  }

  let count = 0;
  for (const el of arr) {
    if (el === delElement) count++;
  }

  count -= amount;

  if (count < 0) {
    return 'В массиве нет такого количества удаляемых элементов';
  }

  return arr.filter((el) => {
    if (el === delElement) {
      if (count == 0) return false;
      count--;
      return true;
    }
    return true;
  });
}

console.log('deleteElArr(arr, 5, 2)', deleteElArr(arr, 5, 2)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6] удалили две пятерки
console.log('deleteElArr(arr, 5, 10)', deleteElArr(arr, 5, 10)); // В массиве нет такого количества удаляемых элементов
console.log('deleteElArr(arr, 10, 2)', deleteElArr(arr, 10, 2)); // В массиве нет такого элемента
```